# AWS Lambda cold start seems to take more time than it prints on Cloud Watch log as (Init Duration : *)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda cold start seems to take more time than it prints on Cloud Watch log as (Init Duration : *) . Now my question is : Is there any way to know time taken from the time it gets triggered (From SQS/SNS) till Lambda actually start working.

Like below CW log tells me that Cold start time is 1493.92 ms, but in fact it was much more.

```
REPORT RequestId: ***** Duration: 13356.72 ms   Billed Duration: 13400 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 187 MB Init Duration: 1493.92 ms
```

Comment: You can enable xray to get a bigger picture.

Comment: How do you know when SQS/SNS triggered the Lambda?